# Debug Flutterwidget

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

[Widget I want to debug with Cross Sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIa4j.png)

I want to debug this widget in Intellji but it s always with this cross so the compiler dont detect the breakpoint. [Here it Ddetect the breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHzBs.png)

but I dont get inside my class, it goes through thousands of classes and I have to click for years. I only want to know what value my weightcontroller has :(

Comment: Have you tried to Right-Click in Android Studio and press on "debug"?

Comment: In this case, you don't need to debug the whole class, Put a breakpoint on the variable `weightContoller` to know its value.

Answer (score 0):

When you are debugging the code , it will first come to the point where it is called first , so checking in the console you will see the hierarchy  in which the code is flowing and where it is breaking !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).